# Passing on LPTA token on webservices call isn't working

Tags: java, security, websphere, ltpa

I've got a j2ee web application using j2ee security, so the identity of the user is propagated from WebSEAL to the application, running in WAS7. I'm now trying to make a SOAP webservices call and propogate the user identity in that webservices call. To do this, I grab the LTPA (WSCredential) and LPTA2 (SingleSignOnToken) using the WSSubject calls and attach them to the webservices call using.

```
bp.getRequestContext().put(Constants.REQUEST_TRANSPORT_PROPERTIES,sendTransportHeaders);
```

where bp is my BindingProvider. This all should work. But when I make a webservices call, I get back this exception.

```
Cause =java.io.IOException: Unable to deserialize the Subjects in this Context
```

I looked at the fields within the LTPA token and all seems right (same realm between the token and the j2ee security realm webservice I'm calling, the token is forwardable, etc), and I cannot find much about this error online, except for (what seems to be an unrelated) case when trying to pass it into the EJB and one case where the realms don't match.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Can you state clearly as to what you are trying to do here?

You should be able to pass the LTPA tokens across transparently with just configuration instead of trying to write some code to achieve the same.

The Web Applications making the Web Service calls to another WebSphere server.

have a quick read at this.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0607_desprets/0607_desprets.html

Things in WAS7 should be very similar to WAS V6.

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 0):

@jeffsix: are you trying to make a webservice call from application running in one websphere server to another application in another websphere server? Make sure LTPA keys are same on both server.